# Split geometry based on postgis function

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have a big geometry of a region or country which I want to split. The output should be 10 splitted geometries of one big geometry based on `ST_MEMSIZE` function of postgis.
For e.g. If threshold of geometry has MEMSIZE 100 and the threshold is 10 then the new table should have 10 splitted geometries. Not sure if a query would do it or if there is postgis function that could do it.

Table

[image: reigon geometry R x]

New_Table

[image: region geometry R_1 x1 R_2 x2]

and so on.

The result of the below query doesn't show the complete geometry as shown in the image.

```
select st_subdivide(geom, 200) from regions where region = 'R';
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A vertex is 16 bytes. You can then compute how many vertices you need per region and use `st_subdivide`. The number of regions will however depends on your data complexity and you may have some large region with just 5 vertices surrounded by small polygons with many vertices.

PS: replace 10000 by your threshold

```
select id,
    st_subdivide(geom, floor(st_memsize(geom)/10000/16)::int)
from mylayer;
```

Comment: The 10000 number, if I keep on increasing from 50, I start losing more and more geometry.

Comment: losing? the subdivided geometries should cover 100% of the original one

Comment: I copied the image in the question itself as I don't know where to paste it.

Comment: Is your geometry valid? (`st_isValid(geom)`). It might be worth trying doing a `buffer(geom,0)` before calling `st_subdivide()`